# using formtastic with forem instead of simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, formtastic, simple-form

I am building my rails app and using forem to integrate forum in it. I have been using formtastic till now and forem uses simple_form.

I want to replace simple_form with formtastic in forem however if I changes simple_form_for with semantic_form_for I am bombarded with error messages.

Is there a simple and sweet way to replace it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems simply replacing all instance of simple_form_for with semantic_form_for does the trick.

Make sure that you have Formtastic gem installed though.